# GCC : Memory zeroing issue

Tags: c, linux

I am new to gdb debugging, seek your help in following issue :

1) I have a program in which following statement copies content from one intermediate buffer to output buffer, which is then written to image file.

```
*OutputBuf->YPtr  = *CurrPatch->PatchBuffer;
```

2) CurrPatch->PatchBuffer is copied from array of size [1048].

3) When I run the program,in the output image there are some patches in the image are black i.e. having pixel value 0 for all pixels in that patch.

4) But when I debug with gdb of put if check

**if(*OutputBuf->YPtr == 0)
printf("OutX = %d OutY =%d *CurrPatch->PatchBuffer=%d\n",OutX,OutY,*CurrPatch->PatchBuffer);
where OutX and OUtY are starting point coordinates of patches.**

in the code it doesn't show *OutputBuf->YPtr becoming zero anytime.

Any pointer as to how to debug this issue? I am trying to check memory leaks / any other memory corruption issues.

```
main()
{

fun1();

fwrite(OutputBuf->YPtr,1,Temp1,OutPtr); /* writing to image file */

}

fun1()
{   
/*local variables*/
.
.
.
.
size = (CurrPatch->PatchWidth) * (CurrPatch->PatchHeight);
CurrPatch->PatchBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
.
.
.

for(l = 0; l < CurrPatch->PatchHeight; l++)
{
  for(m = 0; m < CurrPatch->PatchWidth ;m++ )
  {
        /* Coping from  array   of  static int HighRes1_scale_4[157][1024], k is index*/
    *CurrPatch->PatchBuffer++ = HighRes1_scale_4[k][n++]; 
  }
}

fun2(CurrPatch,OutputBuf);

if(CurrPatch->PatchBuffer != NULL)
{   
    free(CurrPatch->PatchBuffer);
}

} /*fun1 ends*/

fun2(CurrPatch,OutputBuf)
{
/*local variables*/
unsigned char * YPos,*BuffPos;

OutX = CurrPatch->XPos;
OutY = CurrPatch->YPos;

BuffPos = CurrPatch->PatchBuffer;
YPos = OutputBuf->YPtr;

OutputBuf->YPtr = YPos  + (OutputBuf->Width * OutY) + OutX ;

.
.
.
for(l = 0; l < CurrPatch->PatchHeight; l++)
{
  for(m = 0; m < CurrPatch->PatchWidth ;m++ )
  {
    *OutputBuf->YPtr  = *CurrPatch->PatchBuffer;
    if(*OutputBuf->YPtr == 0)
 printf("OutX = %d OutY =%d    *CurrPatch->PatchBuffer= %d\n",  OutX,OutY,*CurrPatch->PatchBuffer);
    OutputBuf->YPtr++;
    CurrPatch->PatchBuffer++;
  }
}


OutputBuf->YPtr = YPos; 
CurrPatch->PatchBuffer = BuffPos;


}
```

Thanks and Regards,

Space

Comment: Is there any chance that you could post some code? Are you `fseek`ing anywhere? Are you only reading and writing in bounds? Are your projection formulas correctly operating?

Comment: Knowing the **full** type declarations of the entities involved would make a *world* of difference in answering this. As-written it looks like you're assigning the value stored at the first element of the patch buffer to the first element of `YPtr` *dereferenced*. There certainly isn't any buffer-copying happening (which couldn't anyway unless the entities in question are structs with array members buried within, and I doubt that is the case). Clip enough code, including typedefs, that *reproduce* the problem into a short `main()` and post that please.

Comment: Thanks   Kaslai and WhozCraig for your replies. will post  the details

Comment: I have posted pseudo code. You help is appreciated

Comment: I did use valgrind it didn't show any memory error.